# How to enable php7 module in apache?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

When I try to run `a2enmod php7.0` - I got message "Considering conflict php5 for php7.0".

After restarting apache - apache can't start.

How to solve this?

Maybe some already enabled modules links to php5?

Params:
Ubuntu Wily,
Apache 2.4.18,
PHP 7.0.4 (works only cli)

Comment: Yes you need to remove and purge php5 to avoid conflict

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First, disable the `php5` module:

```
a2dismod php5
```

then, enable the `php7` module:

```
a2enmod php7.0
```

Next, reload/restart the Apache service:

```
service apache2 restart
```

---

### Update 2018-09-04

wrt [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988990/how-to-enable-php7-module-in-apache/35990093?noredirect=1#comment91260001_35990093), you need to specify exact installed [php-7.x](/questions/tagged/php-7.x) version.

Comment: Yes - it is good solution. And I tried it... But I haven't php5 module, because I deleted all packages with php5. And after "a2enmod php7.0" I can't start my apache.

Comment: @YanDatsyuk run this command `sudo apachectl -t`. See if there's any syntax error.

Comment: Make sure, you are giving the correct version number while enabling php. ie `a2enmod php7.1` for php version 7.1 and `a2enmod php7.2` for php version 7.2. Otherwise, you may end up in error like `Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so` and won't be able to restart apache server.

Comment: There used to be just 7.0 2 years ago @JacobNelson I'll update the reply wrt your comment. :) thanks

Comment: After all, you can also do: `systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 35):

I found the solution on the following thread : https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser

> Im my case not only the php wasn't working but phpmyadmin aswell i did
>   step by step like that
>
> ```
> sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
> sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring
> sudo a2dismod mpm_event
> sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
> service apache2 restart
> ```
>
> And then to:
>
> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> ```
>
> In the last line I do add Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
>
> That make a deal with all problems
>
> Maciej

If it solves your problem, up vote this solution in the original post.

Comment: I've launched also a `sudo a2enmod php7.0` and then restarted apache

Comment: Banging my head against the wall for days now.  This FIXED my "Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe" error.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users looking for solution of same problem. I just repleced

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

in my `/conf/extra/httpв-xampp.conf`

Comment: Yes, I know it can break some other modules dependencies (though I didn't experience them), but if you decided to vote down, please, describe your problem in comments for further consideration