# Getting old php version while installing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I've installed two xampp in different drives(windows) as follow:

```
Drive G: xampp (php 5.6)
Drive C: xampp (php 7.2)
```

I've also set environmental variable to php 7 drive in PATH variable. But still getting error during installing latest laravel that:

```
This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.35) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

When I run following command in CMD it also shows php 5.6.3:

```
php -v
```

System is restarted, CMD is restared, what else I missed or have to do so that I can get latest PHP version? The strange thing is that when I run php file in xampp with 7 version it shows PHP 7.2.4 in phpinfo().

Note: I do need php 5.6 for other old projects that's why I can't delete second xampp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which windows you are using but as i think it is window 10

Make Sure you are adding PATH in your case `C:\xampp\php` in system variables instead of user variables

and try to run `ECHO %PATH%` in cmd and check if there is path added for PHP 7 not 5.6

Comment: yes it's window 10, and I checked by running command in cmd as you said, it's pointing to G:\xampp\php; which is php 5. how can i change it?

Comment: great man thanks, you were right i was adding PATH in user variable. Should I remove it from user variable now? or it's required to be added there too?

Comment: may be in path G:\xampp\php added as i not used windows 10 
but first search G:\xampp\php and replace it with C:\xampp\php

Answer (score 0):

If your using linux just update your default php

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

If your using any other operating system then check how to set default version.

For windows:

Download php from http://php.net/downloads.php and extract it to C:\xampp\php7.2 and set this path.

Comment: it's windows and has set it's path too in environmental variable as shown in attached image.

Comment: @UmairMalik https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988990/how-to-enable-php7-module-in-apache/37159883

Comment: tried the solution mentioned for Window but didn't found what he said in my files.