# laravel new project command is using php@7.3 in place of php@7.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have updated my php from version 7.3 to 7.4.
command `php -v` is showing `PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2020 18:37:21) ( NTS )`

but when i run `laravel new [projectName] --jet`, the laravel project created is with older php version which is 7.3.
I tried `composer global update` and `composer global install` but the response was `Nothing to install, update or remove`.
The issue is how to generate a new laravel project with php 7.4.

The issue relates to creating new project and not installing laravel(that's the difference between this question and the possible duplicates being marked)

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting old php version while installing Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132331/getting-old-php-version-while-installing-laravel)

Comment: On your `composer.lock` change `"platform": {"php": "^7.3"},` to `""platform": { "php": "^7.4"},` then run `composer install` , enjoy

Comment: in my composer.lock, "platform" is like :[], also in my composer.lock, in top this is where php version is being defined: "require": {
                "illuminate/contracts": "^8.0",
                "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
                "psr/container": "^1.0"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the laravel installer, for example:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"
```